# SwiftUi TabView icon size and margin

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've created an basic app with swiftui that contain a bottom tab navigation menu.
[image]

I've a question, it's possible to increase the margin top of the icon? and it's possible to decrease the icon size? this is my code:

```
var body: some View {
        TabView {
            MarketplaceView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("", systemImage: "arrow.right.arrow.left")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                }
            WalletView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("", systemImage: "creditcard")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                }
            My11View()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("", systemImage: "person.3")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                }
            NotificationCenterView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("", systemImage: "bell")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                }
            ProfileView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("", systemImage: "person")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
                }
        }
        .accentColor(Color("m_green"))
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: Instead of SF symbols you can use your own small raster images (say 24x24 for 1x, etc.) and in that case they will use sizes as-is. Otherwise size of icons cannot be changed.

Comment: @Asperi and for margin from the line? there is more space at bottom